# Uniqueness of solution of system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have a general system of $n$ equations and $n$ unkonwns $$Ax=b$$ where we say that the system has a unique solution iff $rank(A)=n$.  This is equivalent to saying that $A$ has no 0 eigenvalues. If, however, the eigenvalues are *arbitrarily* close to 0, does this in any way affect the stability/uniqueness of the solution set? Thanks!

Comment: The system has a unique solution if A's determinant is non-zero and A has an inverse.

Comment: Sure, so of what consequence are eigenvalues that tend to 0?

Comment: That is too advanced for me :(

Comment: Remember that the product of the eigenvalues -- in some sense -- is related to the determinant of the finite dimensional matrix $A$. Depending on how the determinant changes, there will indeed be implications for the solution set if some of the eigenvalues go to zero. Do you have any other specific information in your problem?

Comment: Actually my problem comes from statistics, where the estimator for a model exists if our x matrix has full column rank. Of course, as long as the eigenvalues are non zero, the estimators are identified. However, when the eigenvalues are close to 0, the standard errors get extremely large. This is in a stochastic environment. I was just wondering if this issue would exist in a deterministic environment as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stability of the solution to the system of linear equations $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a rank-$n$ square matrix of dimension $n$, depends on the condition number of $A$. The condition number is defined by the ratio of the maximum singular value of $A$ to its minimum singular value. A lower condition number yields more stable solutions. To give you some intuition, if $A$ is ill-conditioned (i.e. high condition number), a small variation in $b$ induces a big change in $x$.

**Note**: You can solve the problem by multiplying the equation by $A'$ on both sides and taking isolating $x$:
$$x = (A'A)^{-1}A'b.$$
Because $A'A$ is necessarily Hermitian, its eigenvalues are equal to its singular values. Hence, the condition number of $A'A$ is given by the ratio of the maximum eigenvalue to the minimum eigenvalue.